# Firebase Text Recognition

Tags: javascript, react-native, text-recognition, firebase-machine-learning

I tried firebase ml kit and got error this TypeError: (0 , _ml.default)(...).cloudDocumentTextRecognizerProcessImage is not a function

```js
const onPressActionGallery = () => {
    ImagePicker.openPicker({
      cropping: true,
      includeBase64: true,
    })
      .then(async image => {
        const tempPhoto = [...uploadData.photo];
        const photoIndex = tempPhoto.findIndex(
          photo => photo.path === image.path,
        );
        if (photoIndex !== -1) {
          tempPhoto.splice(photoIndex, 1);
        } else {
          tempPhoto.push(image);
        }
        setUploadData(prev => {
          return {
            ...prev,
            photo: tempPhoto,
          };
        });
        const processingResult =
          await ml().cloudDocumentTextRecognizerProcessImage(tempPhoto);
        console.log(processingResult, 'processingResult');
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err, 'err'));
  };
```

Comment: Pls share you code in text and not in image. Also explain a little bit more what and how you tried to do what you want.

Comment: @TarikHuber,  I have attached the code. I want to process the image using Firebase ml kit to show text from the image.

Comment: What package are you using?

Comment: @TarikHuber I am using this package @react-native-firebase/ml

Answer (score 1):

You can use on-device text recognition based on ML Kit https://github.com/a7medev/react-native-ml-kit/tree/main/text-recognition